# Error encountered while parsing a webpage in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, urllib

I have  a python script that takes a url as input and opens the url via urllib and parses a webpage. But I'm getting below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arjun Gaur\Desktop\MyPython\arjurl.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
  File "C:\Users\Arjun Gaur\Desktop\MyPython\urllib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a package
```

below is the file arjsoup.py

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
import BeautifulSoup
import ssl


ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = print('Enter Link : ')
urlstr = urllib.request.urlopen(url,context=ctx).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlstr,'html-parser')

tags = soup('a')

for tag in tags :
    print(tag.get('href',None))
```

Comment: Please include the traceback in the question.

Comment: edited with traceback

Comment: Seems like you have a file named `urllib.py` that you're accidentally importing.

Comment: thnx , i had a file with that name in the same directory .but now am getting a different error

Comment: You're only printing a message for input, instead of getting the actual user input. Change `url = print('Enter Link:')` to `url = input('Enter Link:')`.